# Handle expired web push subscriptions in Chrome

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, push-notification, service-worker, web-push

I noticed that the web push subscription expires daily, I'm not sure how to handle the re-subscription since Chrome doesn't support this event https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerGlobalScope/pushsubscriptionchange_event

Details:

- a subscription is generated in the service worker and posted to the server, stored in the DB
- sever sends web push, it works
- next day when I try to send a web push I get the 410 Gone with the message "push subscription has unsubscribed or expired."

it would be super useful if we could know the lifespan of a subscription and renew it before it expires, I didn't find anything related to that

note: I'm using this gem https://github.com/zaru/webpush to send web push from the server-side